# Question about jQuery and reload a page

Tags: jquery

this is a noob question, so, be generous with me please.

Take for example Twitter. There's an input text form at the top for writing tweet and below the tweets list. If you write a new tweet and click "Tweet" button, you'll see the your new tweet instantly in the tweet list, without reloading a page. I know this is a banal situation but by the way I want to ask you.

I've a page with a form at the top and below it there's a message list. When you fill the form and submit a new message the page it reloads and you see the updated message list with the new message. I want implement the same technique that Twitter use. Maybe should I use jQuery, and send data to a page with `$.post`. Can you explain me something about?

Comment: Can you post your mark-up? Or post something at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate your use?

Comment: Yes, use jQuery and `$.post()`. If you can't get it working, come back here with the code that you tried and I'm sure someone will help you debug it. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ for reference.

Comment: @David I don't have markup, I've a simple form that insert a message in a database and below it show the message list. Very simple. But after each submit the page reloads. I don't want reload but I want the message list will refresh instantly after the submit.

Comment: @dosboy thank you. Now I go to learn some examples about jQuery post. If I have problem I'll come back here. You're very kind man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are a beginner, I think the easiest way would be the one i'll describe.
If you have this div (where you want the new feed to appear):

Markup:

```
<div id="feeds">
   <div class="feed"> Feed 1</div>
   <div class="feed"> Feed 2</div>
   <!-- Your new feed will appear here -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("div.feed:last").clone().appendTo("#feeds").load("newfeed.php?param1=val1");
```

Server (asuming php):

```
<? //newfeed.php
   $param1 = $_GET['param1'];
   $content = "Here put your latest feed";
   echo $content;
?>
```

And that's it.

Now I'll explain what we are doing in that javascript line

```
$("div.feed:last")      //Select the last div with class "feed"
   .clone()             //We clone it, to make space for the new feed
   .appendTo("#feeds")  //We add the clone to the final of the feed list 
   .load("newfeed.php?param1=val1");  //Load it's content with a value got from server
```

When you feel more confortable with jquery, use $.ajax instead.
Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: thank you very much. A practical example is always very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Fred ,

you can use jquery ajax for the same ,

on the ajax success update your DOM html

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/